# Is sudden high bounce rate traffic on one page of my site a negative SEO from competitors?

Tags: seo, bounce-rate, negative-seo

My Google analytics shows %100 bonce rate on one of my website pages in last 2 weeks. All of this traffic is new user and visit this page directly (Not from search engine, paid search or referral) and their time on site are 0. This page is not home page of website and it is about cookies of website. This bounce rate traffic is about 20% of my direct visitors in this specific period and it is amazing for me how it is possible to have such a high number of direct bounce rate traffic with time on site 0 second!

Is it a kind of negative SEO on my website?

Are they a real visitors or it can be a robot?

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's negative SEO, my guess is that you are facing bot's traffic. Check if that traffic matches those indicators:

- Low average session duration.
- High bounce rate (checked).
- Mostly new visitors.
- No goal completion.

In order to minimize the 'bad traffic' take into consideration the following actions:

- Make sure you [exclude traffic from spiders and known bots](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleAnalytics/posts/2tJ79CkfnZk) at Analytics admin settings.
- Exclude bots by IP and User-agent. Check this [blacklist](http://tab-studio.com/en/blocking-robots-on-your-page/).
- Create a new view with 'bad traffic' filtered. Always keep a raw data view.
- Confirm new users with a [captcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3beta.html).

Comment: Thank you Emirodgar for your complete and helpful answer.

Comment: About your Exclude bots blacklist [link](http://tab-studio.com/en/blocking-robots-on-your-page/) , I suggest to exclude below bots from your list: alexawebsearchplatform

Comment: Hi @Emirodgar, Thank you for your good suggestion. About your Exclude bots blacklist, I suggest to remove below bots from your list: alexawebsearchplatform, ask & baidu, because they are not harmful bots. alexawebsearchplatform bot crawl your site for Alexa rank and blocking it caused lose Alexa rank also Ask & Baidu is search engine crawl.